# getting the coefficients of the polynomial

Tags: python, polynomial-math, polynomials

Im doing this as part of an assignment . i have 144 bit  binary keys, each key corresponds to a specific class. each key is split into 8 16 bits segments where each segment corresponds to a one of the coefficients (c8-c0) . and i encoded it in the function :

```
f(x) = c8*x^8 + c7*x^7 + c6*x^6 + c5*x^5 + c4*x^4 + c3*x^3 + c2*x^2 + c1*x + c0
```

where x is a unique integer number that corresponds to a specific class .
so i have a value of fx for each x .

the code below is what i used for encoding .

```
fx = [] 
n = 16
for j in range(0,len(train_unique_label)) :
    split = [kcrc[j][i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(kcrc[j]), n)]
    fx.append(int(split[8],2)*j**8 + int(split[7],2)*j**7 + int(split[6],2)*j**6 + int(split[5],2)*j**5 + int(split[4],2)*j**4
              + int(split[3],2)*j**3 + int(split[2],2)*j**2 + int(split[1],2)*j + int(split[0],2))
```

```
train_unique_label : a list of unique integers 
n :number of bits in each segment
kcrc : list of keys
```

after i encoded it created a dictionary where x is the key and fx is the value of it like shown below :

```
x = train_unique_label
g = dict(zip(x,fx))
```

what i want to do is . whenever i get a value of a specific class i want to calculate the coefficients based on x and fx how can this be done ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, it is not totally clear to me what you are asking. Could you provide us what inputs are and what are expected output?

Comment: Not sure of question but mathematically speaking if you have 8 roots or in your case `x`, `f(x)` pairs you can use Vieta's formulas to get coefficients.

Answer (score 0):

Finding polynomial coefficients using points is straightforward with [`polyfit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.polyfit.html) method from the `numpy` package:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(-4, 5)            # array([-4, -3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3,  4])
y = np.array([-1,1]*4 + [0])    # array([-1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1,  0])

c = np.polyfit(x, y, 8)
#array([-6.32440476e-03,  9.92063492e-05,  1.77430556e-01, -1.38888889e-03,
#       -1.42100694e+00,  4.86111111e-03,  3.24990079e+00, -3.57142857e-03,
#       -1.00000000e+00])
```

As stated in documentation, the method minimizes the squared error. For a  polynomial of order `n`, it takes `n+1` points ore more.

Graphically, this [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) gives:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t = np.linspace(-4.1, 4.1, 100)
p = np.poly1d(c)

fig, axe = plt.subplots()
axe.plot(x, y, 'o')
axe.plot(t, p(t))
axe.grid()
```

[image]